# How to publish content based on a Date field in custom content type in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, rules

I have a Date field in a custom content type in Drupal 7. I would want to control the publishing of the content instance based on that particular Date. I want the job of the Scheduler module but have it as a field in my content type and access it accordingly. Is there a way to do it using triggers or Rules? Any thoughts on this would be really useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is a patch to make the Scheduler "Publish On" date render itself as a field: http://drupal.org/node/1203958

This presents a new Checkbox called "Show Scheduling options in vertical tabs", which you can **uncheck** to display as a field.  Then you give it some weight so it shows up where you want it to.

[image: Scheduler Configuration]
[image: Scheduler rendered field]

It's been working for me in production for a month or so.

**EDIT:** Here's a better way to make this happen with both Scheduler and Rules.

1. Create a Rule, "After saving new content"
2. Add a condition of "Content is of type"
3. Add an "Execute PHP" action with this:

   $node->publish_on = strtotime("[node:field-datefield-here]");
   scheduler_node_insert($node)
4. Create a Rule, "After updating existing content"
5. Add a condition of "Content is of type"
6. Add an "Execute PHP" action with this:

   $node->publish_on = strtotime("[node:field-datefield-here]");
   scheduler_node_update($node);

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I will definitely look at that right away. But I think we should be able to do it using Rules as well. Is there a way to do it using Rules and triggers?

Comment: Edited my answer with a rough Rules scenario.  It's pretty rough!

Comment: Perfect. I would love it if I can use Scheduler module but I can't seem to get the patch working and also would it just show up as a field type? How do I go about it? Any screen shots to help me here would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you're using the 7.x-1.x-dev version of Scheduler. Here is a link to apply a patch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577944/appliying-patch-in-drupal-modules
Or from Drupal.org: http://drupal.org/patch/apply

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Definitely will go through that. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I know this is too much to ask right now but is there a way in which I can just let the Date field govern the publishing of content? I have the 7.x-1.x-dev version installed and I still cannot apply the patch correctly. I followed the exact steps in the links provided. It keeps throwing the error that folder a does not exist. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can't get the patch working, then you could go the Rules route in my answer above... actually I'll edit it with another alternative

Comment: perfect. Let me look at that and see if I can get it to work or not. Thanks a lot Johnathan. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I do not see the node as Scheduled in the Admin screen and somehow it still does not work for me with the rules and the scheduler module. Am I missing something that is critical?

Comment: What code are you using in Execute custom php code?

Comment: the same code that you have mentioned above but replaced the field with my date field, which is field-pub-date

Comment: i would try debugging the field values after you set $node->publish_on = strtotime("[node:field-pub-date]");.  Something like drupal_set_message("[node:field-pub-date]");drupal_set_message($node->publish_on);

Comment: Sure will try that as well. Because if I am adding it to the scheduler, then I should see that node as one of the scheduled nodes and I cannot see it there. So that made me wonder what am I missing to get it to synchronize with the scheduler module.